# Views: attachment inherits exposed filters when set to No

Tags: views

I created a page with an attachment to it. 
Its a Glossary for the Username.

[image: Glossary]
And here is my attachment setting:

[image: Attachment settings]

i Have exposed filters on the page where it is attached to:
[image]

And the Filters works together: When i write something to the name it searches it and when i click on the glossary it retains the name's search value. I don't want that.

If i click on the Glossary i oly want that search, any other filters should reset. How do i achive that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that by default with views settings. Filters are meant to stay upon adding / removing one of them, because otherwise you can't search items combining them. You can add a "Reset" button form the "Advanced" block of the view UI (see screenshot).

[image]

If you want this behavior to be exactly as you describe, I think you'll need write up a plugin for the filters yourself, or alter the default ones.